# gmail receiving html tags - magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, email, controllers

Guys I have a module for sending e-mail, which when sending the e-mail is arriving with the html tags, example: br span, that is, it is not being interpreted. I think the code is read by php as a string and sent as text, but I don't know how to fix it. I've never developed an email trigger module before and I don't know what to do. I've tried using php htmlentities to convert to html but it didn't work. I need help to resolve please.

my controller

```
$SenderText = $post['text']; 

 $text = "<span>";

        foreach ($senderItens as $itens) {
            $text .= $itens . "<br>";
        }

        $text .= "</span>";



$sender = [
 'itens' => $text
]

->setTemplateVars([

 'itens' => $text  
])
```

what do i get

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its very easy. in your email template just use like below

```
  {{var itens|raw}}
```

this will fix your issue

Comment: thank you friend, this was very useful for me

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is this "raw" for?

Comment: you are welcome:) and you can find here more .. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html#non-inline-styles